# The tools palette icons are not in color when opening GIMP 2.10.12

Tags: mac, operating-systems, gimp, macos-catalina

When I open GIMP 2.10.12 the tools palette icons are all in black and white and not displayed in color as shown on the user manuals. Do I need to do something to display the icons in color?

Answer (score 0):

You can change this in the [icon theme preferences](https://docs.gimp.org/2.10/en/gimp-pimping.html#gimp-prefs-icon-theme). *Color* and *Legacy* are two icon themes with colored icons.

[image]